# Expresso Store: Using with Freemember to Save a user's shopping cart

Tags: expresso-store, freemember

I'm working with an ecommerce site powered via the Expresso Store module, and I'm using the Freemember plugin to handle store user accounts and to save billing information for use in the checkout pages. Everything seems to be working great, only when a user logs out and logs back in the cart is cleared every time. However, if you're signed out, add a product to the cart, then sign in, the product remains in the cart. Do I need to pass anything special into the `{exp:store:cart}` loop? Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction? Thanks!

+

EE v2.5.3 / Store v1.6.3 / Freemember v2.2.1

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear... Can you revise to be more explicit about what you are wanting to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

In the Control Panel you can goto Store > General > then scroll down to the bottom and look for "Empty cart on member logout" and change that setting to No.